# show and hide elements when click

Tags: jquery

I would like to hide the first row and show/display the second one.
so when I click on "clearReminder" it will disappear the first image and the image below (second row) it will appear.

```
<a href="#" class="clearReminder" commentID="94"><img src="images/reminder-<?PHP echo $reminder_icon ?>.png" /></a>
<img src="images/reminder-off.png" style="display: none" class="reminder-off" commentID="94" />

<a href="#" class="clearReminder" commentID="95"><img src="images/reminder-<?PHP echo $reminder_icon ?>.png" /></a>
<img src="images/reminder-off.png" style="display: none" class="reminder-off" commentID="95" />
```

AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/clearReminder.php",
    data: info,
    success: function(data){
    $("#loading").ajaxComplete(function()
    {
    }).slideUp();

    if (data == "true")
    {
        $('.clearReminder commentID'+commentID).fadeOut(200).hide();
        $('.reminder-off commentID'+commentID).fadeIn(200).show();
    }
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Calling this on click of a tags element
$(".clearReminder").click(function(el){
  //Hiding All the images 
  $(".clearReminder img").hide();

  //Now Only Showing you the image which is children of the clicked a tag
  $(this).children().show();
})
```

Comment: I tried your code - When I clicked the first img disappear, but the second one doesn't show...